# Can I Force Jquery Dirtyform to See A Form As Dirty?

Tags: jquery, forms

We are using the JQuery dirtyform plugin to display a warning to users if they change form data and try to navigate away from the page and it works well.

One additional thing I would like to do is to force a form to be dirty when the page first loads. I can't figure out how to do this - I've attempted using javascript to change values on the form fields, I've tried adding the "changed" class to form fields, but neither of these trigger the warning dialog when I navigate away from the page.

Is there a way to do this?

ANSWER:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form").dirty_form({includeHidden: true});
   $("a").dirty_stopper();

   $("#dummy").val("1");
   $("#dummy").blur();
});
```

and in the html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dummy" id="dummy" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#myFormID").find("input").change();
```

You'll obviously need to change the selectors, but I think this is what you want. It just triggers jQuery's "change" event (which is what Dirty Form is listening for) on the selected elements.

Comment: @SteveT +1 one for this answer, just in case the plugins has a need to do anything else when a field changes. Good answer @Kennis

Comment: +1 to both answers. @Craig :if it's good, upvote it! (and work towards the sportsmanship badge ;)

Comment: not quite, but you got me on the right track, thanks. dirtyform uses the blur event and can now listen for this event on hidden fields, exactly what I want. I edited in my solution above.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe we're talking about different plugins? This one I found after reading your question (http://mal.co.nz/code/jquery-dirty-forms/) definitely uses change() and not blur(). Either way, I'm glad you've found the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this without having to use hidden fields by adding this function to the plugin:

```
$.fn.set_form_dirty = function(){
    $(this).data("dirty", true);
};
```

Then I call this from the pages that I want to be dirty from start by adding this piece of code (in this case setting all forms on the page to dirty):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").set_form_dirty();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm.. this didn't work for me, but, perhaps the plugin has changed over time. See my answer for what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to apply the class "changed" to an input?

> Whenever an input value changes it
>   will get the 'changed' class added to
>   it

Comment: @SteveT hmmm...what is the link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: The doc you included is from the same plugin - but adding the "changed" class to an element doesn't seem to make the element dirty.